# PDO Return one result as INT and update records based on returned result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to find an integer in a database, and then update a set of records based on that integer. I do not get any errors upon submitting the form, however the value in the database stays as 0, instead of the code_id that was found

Form:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="address">Have a Coupon Code?</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="code" name="code" placeholder="Enter code here">
                <input type="hidden" id="userid" name="userid" value="',$user_id,'">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="add_coupon" value="Apply Code">Apply Code</button>
            </div>
            </form>

if(isset($_POST['add_coupon']))
{
    $user_id    = $_POST['userid'];
    $codeinput  = $_POST['code'];
    $code->apply_coupon($user_id, $codeinput);
    header("location:basket.php?codeadded");
}
```

And the class function:

```
public function apply_coupon($user_id, $codeinput)
     {
       try
       {
            $getcode = $this->db->prepare("SELECT code_id FROM codes WHERE name = :code LIMIT 1");
            $getcode->bindparam(":code", $codeinput); 
            $getcode->execute(); 
            $result = $getcode->fetchColumn(1);

            $applycode = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE basket SET code_id = :result WHERE user_id = :user_id");
            $applycode->bindparam(":user_id", $user_id); 
            $applycode->bindparam(":result", $result, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
            $applycode->execute(); 
            return true;
       }
       catch(PDOException $e)
       {
           echo $e->getMessage();
       }    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PDOStatement::fetchColumn`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) uses a [zero-based index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering). You requested only one column with your query.

```sql
SELECT code_id FROM codes
```

But you were actually requesting the *second* column from that result set by asking for `1`

```
$result = $getcode->fetchColumn(1);
```

That index doesn't exist. So at the very least, you need to change that to zero.

```
$result = $getcode->fetchColumn(0);
```

Or even better, I like to be explicit by asking for the associative index.

```
$result = $getcode->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['code_id'];
```